# "gradle failed to fetch dependencies" with Admob integration in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, admob

Here is the stack trace

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'E:\Projects\R & D\Unity 2018.4.6f1\FacebookAds\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "E:\Projects\R & D\Unity 2018.4.6f1\FacebookAds\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\The Knights-CG\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" "-PTARGET_DIR=E:\Projects\R & D\Unity 2018.4.6f1\FacebookAds\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.4.0"'
stdout:

stderr:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:103)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:957)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__18(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:377)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey10:<>m__28() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:476)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__18() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:363)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__27(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:476)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:116)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:107)
GooglePlayServices.<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__4() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:137)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__18() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error occurs when your project's path is too long and have some characters that disturbs the resolver.

Copy the project folder to some easy to fetch location(like desktop) and resolver will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change directory name 'R & D' to something like 'Test', this is why you have errors. '&' character is not allowed for directory name.